# log transformation doesn't work for 3d plot in plotly

Tags: r, ggplot2, r-plotly, ggplotly

I want to make a rotatable 3d plot. For now I'm using `plotly`. The following code works:

```
require(plotly)
fig <- plot_ly(mtcars, x = ~wt, y = ~hp, z = ~qsec, type="scatter3d", mode="markers")
fig
```

Now, I want to move one or more dimensions to log scale. From the `plotly` manual I thought I should use `layout()`, but this doesn't work:

```
fig %>% layout(xaxis = list(type = "log"), yaxis = list(type = "log"))
```

It builds the same plot, both axes remain linear. What I am doing wrong?